# Launching exe with parameters containing whitespace from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, whitespace, exe, launch

**What I need to do:**
I have a path (copied from a working shortcut) to an .exe that I need to launch from my vb.net application. Following Path:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA client\pnagent.exe" /CitrixShortcut: (2) /QLaunch "Farm1:ADS @ Citrix"
```

**My problem:**
I cannot figure out how to do this. My best guess was

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k " & path)
```

But that always ends up with cmd giving back

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external ...
```

I know this is due to the path not being properly escaped, but I can't figure out how to do it properly. I know about using Double-Doubblequotes ("") but I couldn't get that work either.

If anyone can point me to a maybe better way to do this than Process.Start() I'd be very happy aswell!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Process.Start() overload you want is
Process.Start(*program*, *args*).

... which would give you

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA client\pnagent.exe", "/CitrixShortcut: (2) /QLaunch ""Farm1:ADS @ Citrix"" ")
```

**Edit / Clarification:**
`cmd /k` launches the command shell (aka "DOS prompt") but keeps it open after running the specified command (as opposed to `cmd /c` which executes the command and then closes the shell).
You typically only start `cmd` if you want to execute a shell built-in like `DIR` or `COPY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim MyProcess as string = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA client\pnagent.exe"
Dim MyArgs as string = "/CitrixShortcut: (2) /QLaunch ""Farm1:ADS @ Citrix"""

Process.Start(MyProcess, MyArgs)
```